# Validation using Yup to check number length

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, redux, yup

Yup.number().test('len', 'Must be exactly 5 characters', val => val && val.toString().length === 5)

It's not working correctly. If this field empty, gives a " Must be exactly 5 characters", but should be show nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add nullable() to your yup schema and a regular expression for the numbers, try something like this:

```
const regExp = /\b\d{5}\b/;

Yup.string().matches(regExp, {message: 'Must be exactly 5 numbers', excludeEmptyString: true})
```

Comment: it's not work, I had to add a null checker,but i don't know where and what should i return if value = null

Comment: I don't understand exactly what do you want to achieve, so you want your number to be exactly 5 characters, is not required and it must be not null ?

Comment: It's a not required field, and validation must be  exactly  5 characters
When i don't write anything in that field, it shows an error "Must be a 5 char..."

Comment: if i don't write anytnhing in that field, it doesn't return an error

Comment: Is it a string or a number ?

Comment: in field only allows numbers

Comment: Yup.number().test('len', 'Must be exactly 5 characters', val => val ? val.toString().length === 5 : "something when input = null")

Comment: i think something like this i need

Answer (score 1):

add another check to return true if its empty/null/undefined

```
Yup.number().test('len', 'Must be exactly 5 characters', val => !val || (val && val.toString().length === 5))
```